# "ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials" with correct credentials

Tags: php, ldap

Attempting to implement LDAP authentication on a PHP webapp with the following code:

```
$conn = ldap_connect("ldap://" . $host);
try {
    $user = $username . "@" . $domain;
    ldap_bind($conn, $user, $password);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Log::info($e->getMessage());
}
```

It works for a handlful of people, and doesn't work for others. The following error is being logged:

```
ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

For all users so far, their credentials have been confirmed to be correct using the following command:

```
ldapsearch -H {HOST} -x -W -D {USERNAME}@{DOMAIN} -b '{BASE_DN}' "(userprincipalname={USERNAME}@{DOMAIN})"
```

Anyone know of any possible reasons `ldap_bind` could be failing in the PHP but not on the command line?

Comment: Do you know if there are special characters in the passwords that do not work?

Comment: or is there by chance anonymous bind activated on the ldap-server?

Comment: You may have to escape `$user` as well in case it contains special chars.

Comment: ALso, just an idea, if you take a user for which `user@domain` binding fails in PHP,  what's happening when binding with its dn ? (that you can read from the ldapsearch command) See also [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/497368/ldap-activedirectory-binddn-syntax)

Comment: OpenLDAP or Active Directory? If it's AD, then the error message might have a hex error code that will tell you why it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it ended up working after adding the following:

```
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
```